# How to migrate mongodb schema using prisma? (to create database from the schema)

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, prisma

I am using typescript, but problem is with command line, npx prisma migrate dev doesnt work

Comment: Doesn't `npx prisma db push` command work for you? migrate dev command is not supported for MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Use `prisma generate` to see access your new model from your local `node_modules/prisma`.
When you create a new record, the table will automatically set in your Mongo database.